# achartengine zoom button orientation

Tags: android, achartengine, android-orientation

It`s posssible to change the achartengine orientation **horizontal to vertical**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the current achart library doesn't have this feature.

**EDIT:**

The only alignment feature present in achart engine is **setMargins** which can be used to increase/decrease the graph margins.

```
    // Setting margin width,height for the graph
    // {top , left , bottom, right}
    renderer.setMargins(new int[]{ 80, 60, 20, 20 });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. How to align the zoom button?

Comment: I actually misinterpreted, the setMargins can be used to align the graph. Please see my edit above.